# Can't save multiple lines of data using session on shopping cart

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I'm stuck with this and I think I'm pretty close but the idea just wont come up! I have searched a lot but I can't find anyone with the solution for my specific situation.

I'm making a shopping cart in php with mysql. It's a simple one, you loggin, then go to the store, click the button 'Add to Cart' and the items appear on a gridview with the price and below it, you see the total of the purchase. 
I'm having problems when I need to save multiple lines of data (saleid, username, itemid, etc) from the current session to the database, I just don't know why I can't figured it out, because it's (kinda) the same method of when the user registers in the page.

I'm thinking of making a *for loop* that saves the content of eache SESSION row into the database, like these (it's just an example, I'm awhate that this might be incorrect)

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
while ($_SESSION = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[]= $_SESSION;

    for($i=,$i<$array_rows;$i++){
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO purchase(username,gameid,amount_purchased) VALUES
    ('".$array[$i]."', '".$array[$i]."', '".$array[$i].")");
    $array[$i]=$i+1;
    }
}
```

}

username, gameid, purchasedamount are just some examples! I'm really sorry is this is a stupid question, but I find .php really hard to understand :/

Comment: `while ($_SESSION = mysql_fetch_array($result)){` that's weird, i don't see what your doing with the selected results from an unknown query which is part of this insert loop

Comment: You shouldn't need a session if you don't plan to pass the data between pages. Try replacing the while loop with `while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {}` and removing the `$array[]=$_SESSION;` statement.  This should help you get closer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the values of the cart in an a session variable, lets say $_SESSION['cart'] to save the data from the session cart to the database you would normally do something like

```
    $data = $_SESSION['cart'];

if(empty($data)) return false;

$table = 'purchase';
$implode_values  = array();
$implode_fields = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $implode_fields[] = (string)$key;
    $implode_values[] = Your_db_escape_method($value);  
}

if( mysql_query ("INSERT INTO " . $table . " (".implode(", ", $implode_fields).") VALUES (".implode(", ",$implode_values).")")) {
    //echo 'Data was inserted';
} else {
    //echo 'Data was not inserted';
}
```

or as single query as per your example

```
        foreach($data as $value) {

    mysql_query (
    "INSERT INTO 
        purchase(
        username,
        gameid,
        amount_purchased

    ) VALUES (
        '".$value['username']."', 
        '".$value['gameid']."',
        '".$value['amount_purchased']."')"
     );
}
```

Set the values from your object and store them like this;

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array (
   'username' => 'Usertest_1', // eg 'username' => $obj->username,
   'gameid' => 1234,
   'amount_purchased' => 200
);
```

The above is the same as;

```
$_SESSION['cart']['username'] = 'Usertest_1';
$_SESSION['cart']['gameid'] = 1234;
$_SESSION['cart']['amount_purchased'] = 200;
```

// for multiple records;

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array (
  'username' => 'Username1',
  'gameid' => 1234,
  'amount_purchased' => 200
);

$_SESSION['cart'][] = array (
  'username' => 'username2',
  'gameid' => 1234,
  'amount_purchased' => 200
);
```

save example

```
$data = $_SESSION['cart'];
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO purchase(username, gameid, amount_purchased) VALUES ('".$data['username']."','".$data['gameid']."','".$data['amount_purchased']."')");
  if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
// all ok
 }
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! :)
But my problem now is that the program goes through the true statement saying that the purchased was successful but when I check on the database, no rows are shown. I don't have any clue what the error could be.

I checked the values with print_r and everything there.

Comment: Can you do a print_r($_SESSION['cart']) or whatever you called it and paste it here. I need to see what your array prototype looks like.

Comment: If you want to make sure rows have been inserted use  mysql_affected_rows();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....);
    $num_rows_inserted = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(false === $result OR!$num_rows_inserted){                     // error no rows where inserted
    }

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I did this but now it shows nothing (and the purchased it still not showing). This is the info from the print  

Array
(
    [username] => Usertest  
    [password] => 1234
    [cart] => clsShoppingCart Object
        (
            [prodcount] => 1
            [prod_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => clsGames Object
                        (
                            [gameid] => 1
                            [title] => BIOSHOCK INFINITE
                            [price] => 200
                        )
                )
        )
 )

Comment: Oh, and the output for mysql_affected_rows(); shows nothing. The page just appears blank

Comment: You don’t have the key 'amount_purchased' set and game id is a object property. See my revised answer.

Comment: Also keep in mind mysql_query  is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension. Hope it helps.

Comment: Still not working. Nevermind, I give up. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: No problems, it will work if the array keys and values are correct. I'm not sure why you have stored objects in the session array. Are you sure you have: `username, gameid, amount_purchased` in the array? Check it again right before you try to save it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to keep the value of `$_SESSION` between requests, you shouldn't trash it's value like that.

```
while ($_SESSION = something) { ...
```

See what you are doing with `$_SESSION` here?

`$_SESSION` works just like any other variable, if you overwrite it, you drop its original value.

Also, `for($i=,$i<$array_rows;$i++)` ?

Does this even compile? Try this instead: `for($i=0;$i<$array_rows;$i++)`